# Автообновление отчета power bi с кастомным коннектором

Tags: powerbi

Для сбора данных с appmetrica использовал [кастомный коннектор к power bi](https://github.com/morinad/appmetrica_pq). Но при попытке выставить автобновление вылазит ошибка

> Не удалось определить источник данных из-за неизвестных функций. Для пользовательских соединителей эта ошибка может произойти, если на шлюзе не включено расширение. Подробные сведения: Static analysis failed in gateway. gatewayObjectId:45b36ea5-42f7-40f8-b337-60a8e9902779, resultCode:FailedWithUnknownFunctions Query contains unknown function name: AppMetrica.Stat Unknown function name: AppMetrica.Stat is a valid Mashup library function name format. Hence fail the operation. .
> Источник данных для Query1

Кто-нибудь встречался с такой проблемой и как ее можно решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо [скачать локальный шлюз данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-personal-mode) и установить.